# SMTP gmail with PHPMailer

Tags: email, smtp, phpmailer

I have a problem with PHPMailer. Last month I did with the same script and worked great.

This is the code:

```
$alemail = 'anotherof@yahoo.com';

//send email

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'someof@mydomain.com';
$mail->Password = 'password';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->setFrom('someof@mydomain.com', 'my name');
$mail->addReplyTo('someof@mydomain.com', 'my name');
$mail->addAddress($alemail);
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = 'test';
$mail->Body    = 'hello test';

if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo 'Message was not sent.';
echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

and the error is:
2015-02-04 09:01:01 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Network is unreachable (101) 2015-02-04 09:01:01 SMTP connect() failed. Message was not sent.Mailer error: SMTP connect() failed.

I already check with my server provider and they said no problem with their server side.

I also already do SMTP relay setting on google apps but still not working.

any suggestion?

thanks in advance

Comment: Like it says - your network is unreachable. You could try setting `SMTPDebug = 4` for more verbose info about the connection. [The troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting) may be useful too.

Comment: I tried 'code'SMTPDebug=4 and got this error: 2015-02-04 13:19:59 Connection: opening to smtp.gmail.com:587, t=300, opt=array ( ) 2015-02-04 13:20:41 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Network is unreachable (101) 2015-02-04 13:20:41 SMTP connect() failed. Message was not sent.Mailer error: SMTP connect() failed...  with no idea.. I mean it used to be worked...

Comment: OK, so nothing new there - try all the other things mentioned in the guide.

Comment: @Synchro still no progress.. So that error is not from the PHPMailer and my server provider (based on their test from the guide) either.. then where is the error come from? Thank you for your respond

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for update.. I already solved the problem a few days ago.

Apparently it is server's problem. But when I asked my server provider, they claimed there was nothing wrong with the server smtp connection based on telnet result check:

```
Trying 64.233.169.109...
Connected to gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mx.google.com ESMTP m65sm1615043oif.5 - gsmtp
^]
```

So I asked them to relocate my files to other server and now the PHPMailer script working great.

Thank you @Synchro for your respond.